# How to convert sql to hql with join and max

Tags: mysql, database, hql

I am trying to make this query in hql so i don't have to mapper the query result into my java object , but after trying different options,  i still can't make it work. Is it possible to perform this query in hql in any way? The query is:

```
select t.*
from part_movement t 
  join 
    ( select id_block_movement, max(start_date) as somedate 
      from part_movement 
      where id_area_final_destination = 1
   and ((id_area_destination != id_area_final_destination and id_user_receiver is not null) or
(id_area_destination = id_area_final_destination and id_user_receiver is null))
      group by id_block_movement
    ) s 
    on  s.id_block_movement = t.id_block_movement 
    and s.somedate= t.start_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

ok i got it finally!! It was: (feels wired answearing myself without having any answear from someone else )

```
Query q2 = s.createQuery(" from PartMovement t "
                + " WHERE t.areaByIdAreaFinalDestination = ? "
                + " AND t.startDate IN (select max(b.startDate) from PartMovement b "
                + " WHERE ((b.areaByIdAreaDestination != b.areaByIdAreaFinalDestination and b.usersByIdUserReceiver is not null) OR "
                + " (b.areaByIdAreaDestination = b.areaByIdAreaFinalDestination and b.usersByIdUserReceiver is null)) "
                                                + "  group by b.idBlockMovement )");
```